# Pandas how to group rows by a dictionary of {row : group}

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe n rows:

```
1 2 3 
3 4 1
5 3 2
9 8 2
7 2 6
0 0 0
4 4 4
8 4 1
...
```

and a dictionary of keys , so that row is a key and the value is the group:

```
d = {0 : 0 , 1: 0, 2 : 0, 3 : 1, 4 : 1, 5: 2, 6: 2}
```

I want to group by the keys and then apply mean on the groups.
So I will get:

```
  3 3 2   #This is the mean of rows 0,1,2 from the original df, as d[0]=d[1]=d[2]=0
  8 5 4
  2 2 2
  8 4 1
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the dictionary in the `groupby` it will replace the index value by the dictionary value matching on the key:

```
df.groupby(d).mean()
```

output:

```
       a    b    c
0.0  3.0  3.0  2.0
1.0  8.0  5.0  4.0
2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
```

If you also want to get the missing keys, use `dropna=False` in `groupby`. Those keys will be listed in the 'NaN' group:

```
df.groupby(d, dropna=False).mean()
```

output:

```
       a    b    c
0.0  3.0  3.0  2.0
1.0  8.0  5.0  4.0
2.0  2.0  2.0  2.0
NaN  8.0  4.0  1.0
```

And for a range index instead of the dictionary keys:

```
df.groupby(d, dropna=False, as_index=False).mean()
```

output:

```
     a    b    c
0  3.0  3.0  2.0
1  8.0  5.0  4.0
2  2.0  2.0  2.0
3  8.0  4.0  1.0
```

used input:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  3  4  1
2  5  3  2
3  9  8  2
4  7  2  6
5  0  0  0
6  4  4  4
7  8  4  1
```